# Missing HttpLimitReqModule and HttpLimitZoneModule in Nginx

Tags: nginx, module, jelastic

In the case of using Jelastic cloud with Nginx, how can I set and load *HttpLimitReqModule* and *HttpLimitZoneModule* in Nginx?

I checked the "nginx -V" in the ssh console, above mentioned modules were not included inside the modules list.

And also it seems the Nginx cannot be configured by Jelastic cloud users.

Can you please suggest me a solution?

Comment: > And also it seems the Nginx cannot be configured by Jelastic cloud users.

Do you mean modules, or nginx.conf?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Intellio, these modules are already presented in [Jelastic Nginx](https://docs.jelastic.com/nginx) instances.
For activating of ngx_http_limit_req_module you should to do the following:

1. Add appropriate values for the required modules, for this you should adds to the **http {** the following:

   limit_conn_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=addr:10m;

   limit_req_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=one:10m rate=1r/s;

[image]

2. Specify the appropriate values at the **server {** section like as following:

   limit_conn addr 1;

   limit_req zone=one burst=5;

[image]

3. Apply changes by clicking on the Save button.

[image]

4. Restart your Nginx node.

[image]

Also, following articles may be useful for you:

- [Security Configurations for
  NGINX](https://docs.jelastic.com/nginx-security-configurations)
- [NGINX WebDav Module](https://docs.jelastic.com/nginx-webdav-module)